# Writing test to make sure function is called from subscribe block

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, jasmine

I am trying to write a test for the following subscribe block inside MyComponent

```
ngOnInit() {
// Initalize listener for year dropdown change
    this.yearChangeSubscription = this.searchForm.get('year')?.valueChanges.pipe(
      debounceTime(400),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap((year: string) => {
        return of(year);
      })
    ).subscribe((year: string) => {
      console.log('yearChange');
      this.filterData({ year });
    });
}
```

I want to ensure the filterData function gets called when I change the value in year form control. So I wrote the following spec.

```
fit('should call filterData', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.searchForm.controls.year.setValue('2005');
    fixture.detectChanges();
    flush();
    const spy: any = jasmine.createSpyObj('MyComponent', ['filterData']);
    expect(component.searchForm.controls.year.value).toEqual('2005');
    expect(spy.filterData).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  }));
```

the first expectation is passing but the second is failing.
I can see the `yearChange` console log on the terminal.

Any Idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the `debounceTime` is not being waited upon.

Try this:

```
fit('should call filterData', fakeAsync(() => {
    const filterSpy = spyOn(component, 'filterData');
    component.searchForm.controls.year.setValue('2005');
    // make 401ms pass in a fake way
    tick(401);
    expect(component.searchForm.controls.year.value).toEqual('2005');
    expect(filterSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  }));
```

Comment: Still not working.
I had added ```flush()``` that should have taken care of the wait.

Comment: I am not sure then, sorry. If you see the `log` of `yearChange`, then the test should pass in my opinion.